# Add a hash/pound symbol as the first character in a git commit message in vim

Tags: git, vim

GitHub (probably, wrongly) uses `#`'s when referring to GitHub issues. So I would like to add a commit message that refers to the issue on the first line.

e.g.

```sh
#12: New commit

- Did a thing
- Did another thing
```

Vim/git ignores lines starting with `#`'s though so I'm not sure how to escape it ‍♂️

Comment: It's Git, not Vim, that treats `#` as a comment. (Well, Vim *colors* text based on `#`-as-comment, but that does not affect the end result.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git allows you to update the comment char from the `#` symbol to any other. Then you can use the `#` symbol.

e.g.

```sh
git config core.commentChar '>'
```

or optionally set it globally

```sh
git config --global core.commentchar '>'
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to avoid `git` interpreting the issue number as a comment line, is to insert another character before, so the `#` is not the leading character of the line (a space will do the trick).

Here is an example:

```
#45
```

*will be seen as a comment*

```
 #45
Issue #45
```

*will both be taken entirely as commit messages*

Answer (score 1):

Try:
git commit --amend -m "# ... "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).