# GitKraken makes a commit with empty message is the message I typed in started with # symbol

Tags: git, configuration, version-control, gitkraken

Basically, the title. It only happens in one of my repositories, if I make a commit with a commit message starting with # like "#121: added new feature", when I press commit button, it makes a commit with an empty message. If I then edit the commit message, it saves fine even with # in front. Drives me nuts. Seems like a weird bug or configuration issue. I submitted a support ticket, but didn't get a response, maybe you will help me configure it correctly. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a hash/pound symbol as the first character in a git commit message in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799689/add-a-hash-pound-symbol-as-the-first-character-in-a-git-commit-message-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hash+sign+commit

Comment: @in_vim no, it didn't help. I forgot to mention that if I use SourceTree or anything else, I can freely commit using # symbol in the start